# aggregation cardinality in a UML diagram

Tags: uml, aggregation

I have two doubts related to aggregation. In a class diagram where a class A have an aggregation of class B:
1) Which is the cardinality of the diamond side?
2) Can be expressed that class B has access to A? (the content can see the container)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following design:

[image]

`A` can see `B` as `b` and vice versa can be seen as `a`. The unfilled diamond is a shared aggregation which per UML spec has no fixed semantics (it is suggested to agree upon it's meaning in the current domain). The multiplicities tell that A is aggregated `0..*` times in `B`. Further `1..*` `B`s are visible in A. Now start thinking what that might mean and how aggregation (the shared without fixed semantics) influenced the design.

In contrast the filled diamond is a composite aggregation. It would mean that `A`s lifetime is bound to `B`. So if `B` dies, all it's `A` have to say their last prayer too.

With a composite aggregation there should only be `1` multiplicity at the `B` side or you get into trouble. Here's what he spec says:

> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are objects are deleted with it.

Comment: Can you draw an arrow in the diamond side to indicate that A can navigate to B?

Comment: You can. However, the arrow notation is now replaced by a small dot for showing ownership. Further the role name clearly indicates that you can navigate (since you assigned the role name).

Comment: *"`1..*` `B`s are visible in `A`"* What does this mean?

Comment: @MehdiCharife In coding words: you have an array of  `B`
 objects in `A`

Comment: Doesn't aggregation mean that the side which has the diamond closer to it has an array of elements of the other side?  If you want to convey that each side has an arrray of the other, shouldn't you use two aggregation, each with a diamond on a different side.

Comment: Acrually the hollow diamond has no meaing at all (p. 110 of UML 2.5) It's a shared and not a composite aggregation. The latter only deals with lifetime of the opposite (if I die, you will also!)